# Arduino reads string from another Arduino only if the string is in a loop why?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, serial-data

In my setup I have connected two arduino's Serially. An Arduino Mega is the on that is sending the string and a Arduino Uno is the one receiving it.

- Arduino Mega : RX1(19),TX1(18) - Serial1
- Arduino Uno : RX(10),TX(11)  - using SoftwareSerial
- Gnd is connecetd on both boards

When I send a single string from the mega to Uno multiple times(In void loop)
I receive the string sent infinite number of times on the Uno which is to be expected:

**Arduino Mega - Single string sent multiple no. of times**

```
void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  Serial1.println("e2e4");   
  delay(100);
}
```

Now I want to only send the string a single time, so I inserted an exit(0) or an infinite loop after the delay that is always true.

**Arduino Mega - Single string sent only one time**

```
void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  Serial1.println("e2e4");   
  delay(100);
  while(true);
}
```

**Arduino UNO - code is same for both cases**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial s(10, 11);
void setup() 
{
  delay(200);
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  s.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ;  // wait for Arduino Serial Monitor  
}
void loop() 
{  
  if(s.available()>0)
  {
     Serial.print("\nrec\n");
     delay(100);
     String b = s.readStringUntil('\n');
     delay(100);
     Serial.print(b);
     delay(40);
  }
```

}

Note : Arduino uno is receiving the string using : readStringUntil('\n')

But when I send the string only once I receive nothing on the Arduino Uno, can anyone help me figure out why this is happening

**What I want to know is why the uno receives the string only when it's sent an infinite number of times and not when it is sent 1 time.**

**EDIT (July 8)**

Still haven't got a solution that I'm looking for, if anyone needs any extra information to help me out please mention it to me.

**EDIT (July 8-9)**

Sorry it's my fault for writing Tx1 as 19  and Rx1 as 18 although I did not make the same mistake in the code.
When I pressed the reset button on the mega the string was received on the uno side.How did this happen?  Until now, after I uploaded the code in both the arduino's I opened the serial monitor of the port connected to Uno and I did not receive the string.

Why do I need to reset the mega in order to send the string , shouldn't it work when the serial monitor is opened?

Also I need the mega to send the string automatically without any forced/physical reset is that possible?

I'm asking this because sending a string is part of a larger code where values get updated as time goes by,and a reset will  reset all the values to their original state which I don't want happening.

Comment: A simpler way would be to put the print inside `setup` which is only done once.

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: My question here is not regarding how to print it once. I want to know why I am not receiving anything on the Uno when I only print it once. Even when I print in setup I do not receive the string on the uno.

Comment: Have you used the `while(true)` loop, without `exit(0)`? This is not completely clear

Comment: @chrisl yes I did. I tried once with exit(0) and checked if the string was received on the Uno , then I removed exit(0) and tried using while(true) and checked if the string was received on the Uno then I removed it and tried using goto statement and so on....

Comment: could use int cnt=0; in setup then change the pring to println(cnt);cnt++; this way you will see if you always are misisng the first string sent, or any ones after that.

Comment: two things to try: increase delay(), and remove delay()

Comment: Your posted code does not compile. Please do not post pseudo-code with stuff like "this OR that" in the middle of it. Post the **actual** code that doesn't work. Preferably one without `exit` in it. We can't be expected to debug pseudo-code.

Comment: In addition, post the entire code. Your snippet does not include `setup` which might have relevant information in it.

Comment: @NickGammon edited the question with relevant code.

Comment: How have you wired this up? I'm asking so I can reproduce it. One thing that springs to mind is a race condition. The Mega might be sending the string before the Uno is ready to receive it.

Comment: @NickGammon I have mentioned the wiring in the beginning of of my question. I will put up a diagram if that makes things easier.                                                        
You mentioned that it could be because of a race condition which is highly possible, but when I tried it - by inserting a delay right before the Serial1.println() it did not work. I tried various delay's up to 10 sec.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. With pin 18 (TX1) on my Mega connected to pin 10 (software serial receive), I get the expected message in the serial log if I reset the Mega (thus forcing it to send the message once). Note that you have pins 18 and 19 **reversed** in your question text.  When I said "how have you wired this up?" I was hoping you would actually show what was connected to where (or a photo). If you have 19 on the Mega connected to 10 on the Uno, then it definitely won't work.

Comment: @NickGammon You said you pressed the reset button in mega to force it to send once. How does that work. I actually just tried that now and it worked. Until now, after I uploaded the code in both the arduino's I opened the serial monitor of the port connected to Uno and I did not receive the string. Why do I need to reset the mega, shouldn't it work when the serial monitor is open? Also I need the mega to send the string automatically without any forced/physical reset is that possible?Since this is part of a larger code where values get updated as time goes by,and a reset just clears everything

Comment: If you want to ask a question about saving data into EEPROM then I suggest you make a new question. That is highly tangential to this one.

Comment: you are using an incorrect method for debugging .... do not send the same message multiple times ..... add a sequence number to each message so that each message is different

Answer (score 1):

exit(0) is not the command to use, it is used to completely stop the program, although I'm not sure what happens exactly for an Arduino sketch.

To stop a loop (and continue, normally a break statement is used. This works inside a while or for loop and the sketch continues after the while or for loop where the break statement is executed.

Note, you also can start at the beginning of the while or for loop with the continue statement.

Comment: `exit` turns interrupts off and then goes into an infinite loop. Therefore any pending serial output is not done.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a delay in the arduino mega code to make sure the uno is completely setup before it starts sending the data. I can see some delays in the uno code, so its possible that the arduino uno is not yet ready when the data is sent. Add a large delay, say 2000 to make sure uno is ready. Also there are neater ways to do this instead of just putting an infinite loop, unless the only goal of your program is just to send one string. You can use a flag that to disable sending.

```
bool isSent = true;

void loop()
{
  if(isSent)
   {
     isSent = false;    // set to false so we will never send again.
     Serial1.println("e2e4");   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`exit` turns off interrupts which will stop the serial output. I suggest something simpler like `while (true);`

Comment: i've already mentioned trying that

Answer (score 0):

> Until now, after I uploaded the code in both the arduino's I opened the serial monitor of the port connected to Uno and I did not receive the string.
>
> Why do I need to reset the mega in order to send the string , shouldn't it work when the serial monitor is opened?

Clearly there is a timing issue. When you open the serial monitor it resets the Arduino (in this case, I assume the Uno). So, the Uno resets, however the Mega doesn't reset because you didn't open the serial monitor there. Manually resetting the Mega forces it to send the data again (it would have sent it earlier when powered on).

In normal operation, of course you don't need to reset the Mega just to force a string "to be sent once". You have already proved that you can send a string many times, and sending a string once is clearly a subset of that situation. Sending n times is just (sending once) times n.

Your test setup, which requires powering both Arduinos at the same time, and then opening the serial monitor which resets one, but not the other, is what is confusing you. It is not that you can't send strings whenever you want, in normal operation.